# Deleting item from list

Tags: python

Why does this piece of code:

```
l = [1,2]  
del l[1]  
print(l)
```

print out [1], I assumed that it would delete 1 out of the list and print the remaining 2 as [2]. Thanks

Comment: because indices start at 0 - `l[1]` refers to the second element

Comment: It deletes the element at **index** `1`, not the element that is a `1`

Comment: You are confusing two things - indices and content

Comment: Lists are indexed by position, not by value (that makes no sense).

Comment: Your question can be interpreted in two ways. What would you expect the output to be if `l = ['a', 'b']` initially?

Comment: For testing list operations, I **STRONGLY** recommend not using integers in your list for confusions such as this.  Try again with `l = ['a','b']`

Comment: @AdamHughes Jinx.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1,2]
```

You need to do:

`l.remove(1)`

To delete `1` from the list

---

`del(l[1])` will delete the item at index `1` not the actual element with value `1`

Answer (score 0):

del commmand deletes the value in a list at the given index. Since you typed "del l[1]", that means you want to delete item at the 1st index of the list 'l'. if you want to delete item at 0th index, you should do like = del l[0].

Answer (score 0):

Syntax `l[i]`, where `l` is list and `i` is int, refers to `(i+1)th` element of `l` (indices start at 0), not element equal `i` in `l`.

To remove first element of `l` do:

```
l = [1, 2]
del l[0]
print(l)  # [2]
```

To remove first `1` in `l` do:

```
l = [2, 3, 1, 5, 1]
l.remove(1)
print(l)  #[2, 3, 5, 1]
```

To remove all `1`s from `l` do:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1]
for i in range(l.count(1)):
    l.remove(1)
print(l)  # [2, 3, 5]
```